# Javascript svelte.js

Tags: svelte

Many thanks about this piece of code.

```
export const page;

router('/access', () =>
    import('./views/access.svelte').then(
    module => page.set({ component: module.default })
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- page in `import router from 'page'` most likely refers to [page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/), a JavaScript router (that doesn't have any Svelte dependency)
- `module.default` refers to the default export of the file that is passed as the first argument to the `import()` function. This file would be `'./views/dashboard.svelte'` in

  ```svelte
  router('/dashboard', () =>
      import('./views/dashboard.svelte').then(
          module => page.set({ component: module.default })
      )
  );
  ```

  As all the imported files are Svelte components, the default export would be the component itself.
- *Why* props are defined as empty I can't tell. But possibly, none of the components specified in `import(/*component path here*/, /*more code here*/)` requires any props.

Also, note that, although initially the page store is initialized with an object that has both, a `component` and `props` field, the page store's value is subsequently overwritten with an object that just has the `component` field (at all the calls to `page.set()`).